# JQuery event handling dependant selects/checkboxes (code incl.)

Tags: jquery, checkbox, event-handling

I am trying to make dependant elements created dynamically: 2 selects and one checkbox. 
Selects: subtitulo is created after and depends on the value of titulo
Checkbox is created after and depends on the value of subtitulo

Each element is contained within it's own  which I create in runtime on the functions resultsTitulo, resultsSubtitulo, resultsPuntos. For each, I detect if it's the first time it is created, to create the , if it is not, I keep the  but destroy the element structure (ie. $("#titulo").replaceWith('');) and recreate it again. All  elements are contained within another main  called "info" (HTML file)

`$(document).ready(function())` initializes the first select and detects changes in state of all the elements.

I'm having the following problems:

1) I want to be able to detect event changes depending on their type of element, ie. `$("div.info").change(function () -> $("#titulo").change(function ()`

However, this does not work.

2) I want to be able to add the structures not inside  but inside

```
$("div.info").append("<div class=\"tituloD\">");
$("div.info").append("Titulo: "); -> $("div.titulo").append("Titulo: ");
```

This doesn't work either.

3) I don't know if the checkbox would be created well...

```
var tituloCreado = "No";
var subtituloCreado = "No";
var puntosCreados = "No";
var temp = 0;

// Esta funcion recoge el json data de titulos y lo imprime en pantalla
function resultsTitulo(data) { 
    $("div.info").html('').show(); 


    //Si el título no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(tituloCreado == "No"){
        $("div.info").append("<div class=\"tituloD\">");
        $("div.info").append("Titulo: ");
        $("div.info").append("<select id=\"titulo\">");
        $("#titulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un titulo");

        //Rellenar el titulo con las posibles opciones
        $.each(data,function(index,value) { 
            $("#titulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });

        $("div.info").append("</select>"); 
        $("div.info").append("</div>");
        tituloCreado = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#titulo").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $("div.info").append("<select id=\"titulo\">");
        $("#titulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un titulo");

        //Rellenar el titulo con las posibles opciones
        $.each(data,function(index,value) { 
            $("#titulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });

        $("div.info").append("</select>");  
    }
    $("div.info").append("<br />");
    $("div.info").append("<br />");
} 



// Esta funcion recoge el json data de subtitulos y lo imprime en pantalla  
function resultsSubtitulo(data) { 

    //Si el subtítulo no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(subtituloCreado == "No"){
        $("div.info").append("<div class=\"subtituloD\">");
        $("div.info").append("Subtitulo: ");
        $("div.info").append("<select id=\"subtitulo\">"); 
        $("#subtitulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un subtitulo"); 
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("#subtitulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });
        $("div.info").append("</select>"); 
        $("div.info").append("</div>");
        subtituloCreado = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#subtitulo").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $("div.info").append("<select id=\"subtitulo\">"); 
        $("#subtitulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un subtitulo"); 

        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("#subtitulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });
        $("div.info").append("</select>");
    }

} 

// Esta funcion recoge el json data de puntos importantes y lo imprime en pantalla  
function resultsPuntos(data) { 
//$("div.info").append(""); 
    //Si el punto no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(puntosCreados == "No"){
        $("div.info").append("<div class=\"puntosD\">");
        $("div.info").append("Puntos importantes: ");

        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("div.info").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
        });
        $("div.info").append("</div>");
        puntosCreados = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#myCheckbox").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("div.info").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
        });
    }
}



//INICIO
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({ 
        data: "", 
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: "json", 
        url: "recogeTitulo.php", 
        success: function(data){ 
            resultsTitulo(data); 
        }
    });

    $("div.info").change(function (){
        $("div.info option:selected").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();               
                $.ajax({
                        data: "valor="+value, 
                        type: "GET", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        url: "recogeSubtitulo.php", 
                        success: function(data){ 
                            resultsSubtitulo(data); 
                        } 
                });
        }); 
    }); 

});
```

Comment: some problems in your code: `append` is not supposed to work this way. You append dom elements or strings that are parsed into dom elements. `$('#somediv').append('</div>')` doesn't work. See http://api.jquery.com/append/ for the correct usage. Also, please clarify what you want on item 2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marcelo for your quick reply, it made me think about what I was doing. 
Everything is working correctly with this code except for one thing: once the checkboxes are created and shown:

```
$.each(data,function(index,value) {
$("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
```

they are not eliminated and substituted:

```
$("#checkbox").replaceWith('');
```

**How can I do this?**

This is my new code. First I rewrote my HTML, substituting the "info div" with this:

```
<div class="tituloD">
</div>
<div class="subtituloD">
</div>
<div class="puntosD">
</div>
```

And rewrote the code for the javascript, hopefully now I am using "append" correctly.

```
var tituloCreado = "No";
var subtituloCreado = "No";
var puntosCreados = "No";

// Esta funcion recoge el json data de titulos y lo imprime en pantalla
function resultsTitulo(data) { 
    $("div.tituloD").html('').show(); 


    //Si el título no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(tituloCreado == "No"){
        $("div.tituloD").append("Titulo: ");
        $("div.tituloD").append("<select id=\"titulo\">");
        $("#titulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un titulo");

        //Rellenar el titulo con las posibles opciones
        $.each(data,function(index,value) { 
            $("#titulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });

        $("div.tituloD").append("</select>"); 
        tituloCreado = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#titulo").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $("div.tituloD").append("<select id=\"titulo\">");
        $("#titulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un titulo");

        //Rellenar el titulo con las posibles opciones
        $.each(data,function(index,value) { 
            $("#titulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });

        $("div.tituloD").append("</select>");   
    }
    $("div.tituloD").append("<br />");
    $("div.tituloD").append("<br />");
} 



// Esta funcion recoge el json data de subtitulos y lo imprime en pantalla  
function resultsSubtitulo(data) { 

    //Si el subtítulo no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(subtituloCreado == "No"){
        $("div.subtituloD").append("Subtitulo: ");
        $("div.subtituloD").append("<select id=\"subtitulo\">"); 
        $("#subtitulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un subtitulo"); 
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("#subtitulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });
        $("div.subtituloD").append("</select>"); 
        subtituloCreado = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#subtitulo").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $("div.subtituloD").append("<select id=\"subtitulo\">"); 
        $("#subtitulo").append("<option value='0'> Elige un subtitulo"); 

        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("#subtitulo").append('<option value="'+data[index].id+'">' + data[index].nombre + '</option>');
        });
        $("div.subtituloD").append("</select>");
    }

} 

// Esta funcion recoge el json data de puntos importantes y lo imprime en pantalla  
function resultsPuntos(data) { 

    //Si el punto no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(puntosCreados == "No"){
        $("div.puntosD").append("Puntos importantes: ");
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
        });
        puntosCreados = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#checkbox").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
        });
    }
}



//INICIO
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({ 
        data: "", 
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: "json", 
        url: "recogeTitulo.php", 
        success: function(data){ 
            resultsTitulo(data); 
        }
    });

    //Eventhandler tituloD
    $("div.tituloD").change(function (){
        $("div.tituloD option:selected").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();               
                $.ajax({
                        data: "valor="+value, 
                        type: "GET", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        url: "recogeSubtitulo.php", 
                        success: function(data){ 
                            resultsSubtitulo(data); 
                        } 
                });
        }); 
    }); 

    //Eventhandler subtituloD
    $("div.subtituloD").change(function (){
        $("div.subtituloD option:selected").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();               
                $.ajax({
                        data: "valor="+value, 
                        type: "GET", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        url: "recogePuntos.php", 
                        success: function(data){ 
                            resultsPuntos(data); 
                        } 
                });
        }); 
    });     

});
```

Comment: You might want to read more about something called `boolean` types. They are very helpful. Otherwise consider accepting your own answer.